# how to compulsively send <input> data in a form in html file OR why I cannot send it

Tags: php, html

Here's the thing:
I put a `<input type='checkbox' name='a'>` in a `<form action="b.php" method="GET">` but I can not get `'?a=something'` actually from url.
I don't know what's wrong because I use several `<div>`s by nesting them and also some css style and bootstrap classes.

My complete code is as below.

```
<form action="addfile.php" name = "fileinfo_form" method="GET">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">SHA1</span>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox" id ="sha1checkbox" name="sha1checkbox"><!--I cannot get sha1checkbox's value from url -->
        </span>
        <input type="text" name="sha1code" class="form-control" placeholder="Sha1 Hash Code" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Just a comment, try using POST instead of GET method for secure transfer of form data.

Comment: I tested it localy. If I check the checkbox, the URL contains "sha1checkbox=on", if I don't the parameter is missing. I guess that is expected behaviour

Comment: @Sebastian yes. if I check it then url contains information of it . but how can I make sure it is always in url? if I do nothing then there is supposed to be a "sha1checkbox=off" in url.

Comment: iirc, checkboxes values are found in the page that receives the form only if they are checked, when they are not, the var doesn't exist (it is the same with POST)

Comment: @Kaddath: I guess that will only work if you use a hidden field and if you set the value with JavaScript ... Why do you need the parameter to be always set? If it is not set, consider it to be false

Comment: @Sebastian i assume he asks for a reason, maybe for a URL rewrite stuff?

Comment: My question was aimed at @chucklai. Sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine.

When the checkbox is checked, the result in the url will be `addfile.php?sha1checkbox=on&sha1code=test`.

If it is not checked, it will not return any value in the GET method via URL for that checkbox. Something like `addfile.php?sha1code=test` is returned only but if you use POST you can tell if it is checked or not in php code.

This is the normal behaviour of the checkbox in html forms. Don't be worried.

You can insert the following code in your destination file to test if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sha1checkbox'])){
    echo "It is set";
}else{
    echo "it is not";
}
```

So you do not need to worry about it appearing in the url unless you plan on using the url in some way.

Comment: how can I make sure it is always in url? if I do nothing then there is supposed to be a "sha1checkbox=off" in url

Comment: if you want to be sure it is in the URL, you can have a hidden input whose value is changed by javascript when you click on the checkbox. Then you check this value and don't bother about the checkbox's one

Comment: Hey @chucklai, you do not need to worry about it showing up in the url because if you check in destination file, it will display the status. I have updated my answer to show you the test code

Comment: asset works fine, thank you all!!!  my coding style is too perfectism. haha